# Don't work border when you hover DIV

Tags: html, css, hover, border

I need when you hover a mouse on one div  other div with parametres appear from below and these both divs have common border.

Now I have border only on first div. It looks like first div don't contain second, but in html code div with parametres is beetwen  of first.

What is wrong?

```css
.item {
 width: 220px;
 height: 300px;
 margin: 10px 3px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 }

.item:hover .item_inner {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 10;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 height: 100%;
}

.item_param {
 display: none;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 0 5px;
 margin: 10px 0;
 background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
 
.item_inner{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 border: 1px solid green;
}

.item_inner:hover .item_param {
 display: block;
 top: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item_inner">
    TEXT
   <div class="item_param">
    <p>Parametres</p>
    <p>Parametres</p>
    <p>Parametres</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.item_inner:hover .item_param {
    display: block;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank, but don't work as I need. It might be like this http://joxi.ru/l2Zv35wu8MGYE2